# iptables - Redirect except list MAC Address

Tags: networking, iptables, router

I'm using iptables on my router to redirect all web traffic to my page.

But i don't know how to except my mac address list.

I did command like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac ! --mac-source xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080 (Host A)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac ! --mac-source xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080 (Host B)
```

But it just execute command for host A. It means Host A can access web normally but Host B still got redirect.

How can i got access normally for both mac address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -j ACCEPT (Host A)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -j ACCEPT (Host B)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The first two commands ACCEPT packets from A and B, so redirection only happen if the packet is from another host.

Comment: With your order all work perfectly. But what if i want add more mac address after the third commands?

Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @TrầnMinhPhương You can insert a command in the middle with "iptables -I".

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. What is your mean?

Comment: @TrầnMinhPhương I assume you were asking how to add more addresses after executing my commands. Or were you asking what would the commands be if you want more addresses?

Comment: Yes, after execute your third command, all traffic will redirect.

I want add more mac address like this:

<pre>iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx -j ACCEPT</pre>

after execute your third command.

Comment: @TrầnMinhPhương iptables's -I option works exactly like -A, excepts it lets you insert a command into the middle of a chain instead of appending to the end.

Comment: Okay man, thank you so much. You saved my day! :)